# Is there a way to do Count Query in Azure MobileServiceSyncTable?

Tags: java, android, azure, mobile

I'm developing an app (Android) which uses Azure Mobile Apps with offline sync, and I'm trying to get any information about how to create queries to MobileServiceSyncTable (i.e. queries to local sqlite database). It would be nice to see SQL queries and Azure ORM equivalent, for example:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id = "1" : Query query = QueryOperations.field("id").eq(val("1"));
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id <> "1" : Query query = QueryOperations.field("id").ne(val("1"));
SELECT COUNT("id") FROM ...  - ???
SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY ... DESC - ???
```

and so on. I've checked tutorials and docs, but tutorials show only simple usecases. In case of using MobileServiceTable (no offline sync), syntax is like LINQ. But in case of using MobileServiceSyncTable, syntax is not obvious.
Has anyone created mobile apps with MS Azure Mobile backend with offline sync?

Comment: documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-offline-data

Comment: yes, I've checked this tutorial. But there are only very simple use cases. And, for example, how to build query with COUNT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed the source code & javadocs of Azure Mobile Apps SDK for Android client, then I discovered there is not any method in the classes [`MobileServiceSyncTable`](https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/table/sync/MobileServiceSyncTable.html), [`QueryOperations`](https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/table/query/QueryOperations.html) & [`Query`](https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/table/query/Query.html) for directly supporting some features like count rows, ordering, etc.

If you want to get the count number when retrieve data, you can use the method `includeInlineCount()` of class `Query` to add the inlinecount property to the result.

Otherwise, there seems to be a workaround way for counting rows or other queries, which comes from the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/blob/3e1cd0995e301c829514b05b7a2769e63625e81e/sdk/test/sdk.testapp/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/sdk/testapp/test/helpers/SQLiteStoreTestsUtilities.java#L40) of unit testing for Android client, that is directly build sql query for SQLite on Android to get the data as you want, because the offline sync feature is for syncing between SQlite and Azure Mobile Apps.

Hope it helps.

---

Per my experience, the workaround ways below to count rows.

1. Using custom api with backend logic for counting.
2. Using `includeInlineCount` method with paging for a large size table.

Comment: I've checked source code, and I've seen method 'includeInlineCount()'. And I thought about this way. But, I'm thinking, if I try to get count of rows in large table, will framework pull all the data from database in this case?

Comment: @zampotex Indeed, for your thought. So using `includeInlineCount()` seems not to be a good idea for counting in a large size table.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the way to create ordered queries:
In case of query with WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * FROM <TableName> WHERE <field1>=<value> ORDER BY <field2> DESC :
QueryOperations.field("field1").eq(val("value")).orderBy("<field2>", QueryOrder.Descending);
```

In case of simple ordered query (get all rows):

```
SELECT * FROM <TableName> ORDER BY <fieldName> DESC :
QueryOperations.field("id").ne(val("")).orderBy("<fieldName>", QueryOrder.Descending);
```

It's dirty, but it works. Building queries is described in [this tutorial](http://hashtagfail.com/post/46493261719/mobile-services-android-querying). Though it's about MobileServiceTable (no offline sync), syntax is similar.

But the question about the COUNT remains open.